# Macbook pro external display (while in clamshell mode) won't sleep all of a sudden

Tags: macos, display, sleep-wake, screensaver

before, when I left my macbook pro alone for 15 minutes in clamshell mode the external display would go to sleep instead of putting on a screen saver. Now all of a sudden it goes into screen saver and I have to manually put the display to sleep (using hotkeys). does anyone have any idea why this could be ? If it helps i'm running 10.10.5... and my power savings setting hasn't changed.

Comment: I assume by "clamshell" you mean closing the lid? Did you check your screen saver settings? It should be the same or less that the display sleep in the Energy settings.

Comment: so what your saying is that if my screen saver time is greater than my display sleep time it won't work ?

Comment: In order to actually reply to this we would have needed to know your actual screen saver and power saving settings.